# How to store the modified content of a webpage when in offline mode, before coming back online again

Tags: javascript, firefox, web, offline, kallithea

After accessing a webpage with dynamic content, I use the "work offline" functionality of my web browser, and then I play around a bit with the page.
Later on, I turn back to mode "online" in my browser so that my changes can be appropriately stored in the corresponding server.

What can I do to "save" the information related to the webpage when working offline (so that I can close my browser or reboot my PC) and reopen it later (before turning back to "online" again?

Some extra information:

- The page in question is a page provided by a remote Kallithea server.
  For example, a similar context can be accessed via this link:
  https://kallithea-scm.org/repos/kallithea/changeset/9e750b37b391af137aee703532082059ae6a3e25
- Currently using Mozilla, but responses for any browser are welcome

Answer (score 1):

You can save your data to the [local storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) using javascript.

You can also look into [service workers](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/primers/service-workers) if you have to intercept browser request (but they are not available in all browsers). Google also has a project called "Progressive Web Apps" to deliver offline functionality and faster load time: [link](https://developers.google.com/web/progressive-web-apps/).

Comment: I am not sure about the javascript local storage, as I am not a JavaScript user.  Could you give more details?  In any case, I cannot modify the source of my webpage.

Comment: If the page does not support working offline and you cannot change the page, there won't be much you can do. Just to check if understand you. You want to do somethings like: Write a Facebook post while you are offline, close the browser, come back to the website when you are online again und then have your post saved to the server?

Comment: Something similar to that.  Concretely: load my facebook page, switch to work offline in my browser, "write my post", save (somehow)  those local modifications, close my browser. Open my browser, load the saved information in the browser, switch to work online again in my browser, and at last, save.

In my concrete case, it is (of course) not Facebook, but a webpage generated by a Kallithea server.

Notice that the modifications that I introduced into the page are effectively stored if I "save the page".

Comment: What you describe is quite a complex procedure (I am not even aware of a webpage that supports this at the moment). The behavior is much more like an app. This is definitely something that the owner of the page has to code. I would still recommend the local storage and to take a look at Progressive Web Apps, which go into the same direction. If you are not the owner of the website, I am not aware of a way to achieve that